# How to Names from three tables whose reference is in fourth table

Tags: sql

I am working on a SQL query. I have following tables

- `Class` (`ID,Name`)
- `Competition` (`ID,Name`)
- `Month` (`ID,Name`)
- `Student` (`ID,Name,Class,MonthEnrollment`)

All these tables have been referenced in table

```
Competition_Result(ID,Class,Competiton,Month,First,Second,Third)
```

First, Second and are the students_ID. To get competition result happened in month 1 I have used following sql query:

```
SELECT     
    Competitions.Name AS Comp, Students.Name AS Student, 
    Class.Name AS ClassName, Competition_Result.*
FROM Competition_Result 
INNER JOINCompetitions ON Competition_Result.Competition = Competitions.ID 
INNER JOIN Students ON Competition_Result.First = Students.ID AND Competition_Result.Second = Students.ID AND  Competition_Result.Third = Students.ID 
INNER JOIN Class ON Competition_Result.Class = Class.ID
```

but it is not working..Please help me on this

Comment: Why it's not working? Do you have an error?

Comment: No i have not any error.But i am not getting desired result.i have inserted 3 names in Student Table.and reerenced these 3 student ID in Competion_Result table in Columns First,Second and Third respectively.i want names of all 3 students and their class and month also.but my query is not working.

Comment: I suppose you are working with something that you already but I hope you realize that is very inefficient design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the table students multiple times, because your first, second and third place are different, so nothing can fulfill the condition (think of transitivity) if the three values are the same, the query would work, but that seems to be impossible in your model.

```
ON  Competition_Result.First = Students.ID 
AND Competition_Result.Second = Students.ID 
AND Competition_Result.Third = Students.ID
```

Try this query (although it's hard to tell what is your problem.)

```
SELECT 
    competitions.name as comp, 
    first.name as first, 
    second.name as second, 
    third.name as third, 
    class.name as classname, 
    competition_result.*
FROM competition_result 
    INNER JOIN competitions 
        ON competition_result.competition = competitions.id 
    INNER JOIN students first
        ON competition_result.first = first.id 
    INNER JOIN students second
        ON competition_result.second = second.id
    INNER JOIN students third
        ON competition_result.third = third.id 
    INNER JOIN class 
        ON competition_result.class = class.id
```

Comment: onw more thing sir i want month name also..kindly help me to get month name also

Comment: Actually Sir I do not have sufficient reputation because i am a new user. That's why i can't Upvote it.